# Is there any way to resolve this Gradio Output Error

Tags: python, gradio

When I run the code outside of gradio, I get the results I want. But within radio I get error.
[Gradio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTf1g.jpg)

[User Interface Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19CzQ.jpg)

When I run the code outside of gradio, I get the results I want. But within radio I get error.

Comment: Don't post pictures of your `code`, write them in your post so others can use your code to solve the error.

Comment: That doesn't say anything about what the error is.  If you click that button, do you get details?